# Django/Apache/mod_wsgi not using virtualenv's Python binary

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I have a virtualenv at /opt/webapps/ff/ with its own Python installation.  I have WSGIPythonHome set to /opt/webapps/ff in my Apache config file (and this is definitely getting used in some capacity, because if I set it to a slightly different existing directory and restart Apache I get a 504).  But if I e.g. `assert False` in a view somewhere to bring up the Django debug page, I see that settings.PYTHON_BIN is `/usr/bin` rather than `/opt/webapps/ff/bin`.

How do I get Apache/mod_wsgi to use my virtual environment's Python binary?  I thought setting WSGIPythonHome was the way to do this, but it only seems to affect which site-packages dir is used, not which binary is used.  Thanks.

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 8):

These are the instructions I used which seem to be working well.

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/VirtualEnvironments

> Using 'site.addsitedir()' is a bit
>   different to simply adding the
>   directory to 'sys.path' as the
>   function will open up any '.pth' files
>   located in the directory and process
>   them. This is necessary to ensure that
>   any special directories related to
>   Python eggs are automatically added to
>   'sys.path'.
>
> Note that although virtualenv includes
>   the script 'activate_this.py', which
>   the virtualenv documentation claims
>   should be invoked using 'execfile()'
>   in the context of mod_wsgi, you may
>   want to be cautious using it. This is
>   because the script modifies
>   'sys.prefix' which may actually cause
>   problems with the operation of
>   mod_wsgi or Python modules already
>   loaded into the Python interpreter, if
>   the code is dependent on the value of
>   'sys.prefix' not changing. The
>   WSGIPythonHome directive already
>   described should instead be used if
>   wanting to associate Python as a whole
>   with the virtual environment.
>
> Despite that, the 'activate_this.py'
>   script is an attempt to resolve an
>   issue with how 'site.addsitedir()'
>   works. That is that any new
>   directories which are added to
>   'sys.path' by 'site.addsitedir()' are
>   actually appended to the end. The
>   problem with this in the context of
>   mod_wsgi is that if WSGIPythonHome was
>   not used to associate mod_wsgi with a
>   virgin baseline environment, then any
>   packages/modules in the main Python
>   installation will still take
>   precedence over those in the virtual
>   environment.
>
> To work around this problem, what
>   'activate_this.py' does is invoke
>   'site.addsitedir()' but then also
>   reorders 'sys.path' so any newly added
>   directories are shifted to the front
>   of 'sys.path'. This will then ensure
>   that where there are different
>   versions of packages in the virtual
>   environment that they take precedence
>   over those in the main Python
>   installation.
>
> As explained, because
>   'activate_this.py' is doing other
>   things which may not be appropriate in
>   the context of mod_wsgi, if unable to
>   set WSGIPythonHome to point mod_wsgi
>   at a virgin baseline environment,
>   instead of just calling
>   'site.addsitedir()' you should use the
>   code:

```
ALLDIRS = ['usr/local/pythonenv/PYLONS-1/lib/python2.5/site-packages']

import sys 
import site 

# Remember original sys.path.
prev_sys_path = list(sys.path) 

# Add each new site-packages directory.
for directory in ALLDIRS:
  site.addsitedir(directory)

# Reorder sys.path so new directories at the front.
new_sys_path = [] 
for item in list(sys.path): 
    if item not in prev_sys_path: 
        new_sys_path.append(item) 
        sys.path.remove(item) 
sys.path[:0] = new_sys_path
```

> If you still want to use the
>   activation script from virtualenv,
>   then use:

```
activate_this = '/usr/local/pythonenv/PYLONS-1/bin/activate_this.py' 
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))
```

> If the fact that 'sys.prefix' has been
>   modified doesn't give an issue, then
>   great. If you see subtle unexplained
>   problems that may be linked to the
>   change to 'sys.prefix', then use the
>   more long handed approach above
>   whereby 'site.addsitedir()' is used
>   directly and 'sys.path' reorderd
>   subsequently.

Here is a discussion about this issue as well

http://groups.google.com/group/modwsgi/browse_thread/thread/466823f087070b5f?pli=1

Comment: Thanks, this didn't actually solve the problem, believe it or not...but it seemed like a good suggestion when I read it.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same situation in a Pylons app and ended up using `/usr/bin` binary **plus** virtualenv site-packages dir instead.

Of course it was the same python version...

Comment: Thanks, yeah, the site gets served okay like that...until it doesn't.  I'm trying to make things more portable.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a virtualenv, you need to be sure to activate it within the WSGI script.

```
venv_path = "/opt/webapps/ff"
activate_this = os.path.join(venv_path, "bin/activate_this.py")
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))
```

Comment: Thanks - I thought this was going to solve the problem, but when I got home and tried it, it actually didn't.  When I had a typo (`'opt/webapps/ff'`, missing the first slash) I got an Apache error, which went away when I fixed it...so it was getting read, but it wasn't affecting which python binary got used.

Answer (score -1):

I have encountered the same issue when installing modoboa (django based) in virtualenv.

It took me a lot of time to find a clear answer, so I will post it here.

All I needed to do was adding two lines to the general apache conf file (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf in CentOS):

```
WSGISocketPrefix /var/run/wsgi ## (location for the PID)
WSGIPythonHome /path/to/virtualenv
```

And restart Apache